# Shiny scope rules with reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny

I tried defined function to the change some reactive values inside `observeEvent`. But if I define function outside of `shinyServer`, it's not works. Minimal example below:

```
library(shiny)

set_values <- function() v$i2 <<- v$i2 + 1
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("inc", "Increase")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("text")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    set_values2 <- function() v$i1 <- v$i1 + 1
    v <- reactiveValues(i1 = 0, i2 = 0)
    observeEvent(input$inc, set_values())
    observeEvent(input$inc, set_values2())
    output$text <- renderPrint({
       print(v$i1)
       print(v$i2)
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I tried click on the Increase button, app crashed with the following warning:

```
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: object 'v' not found
observeEvent(input$inc)
```

Variant with the `set_values2()` only works as well.

Comment: You can create function with v as input `set_values <- function(v) v$i2 <- v$i2 + 1`  and `set_values(v)` .. its must work

Comment: @Batanichek: already tried that. It works.